# How can I write React component that returns a class component as a functional component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, authentication, higher-order-components

**My Goal:**

I'm currently implementing an `AuthUserRole` HOC  component to handle the user roles: Manager and Employee. [I'm using this tutorial](https://blog.vcarl.com/role-based-authorization-react/) to do so, but they use a functional component to return a class component.

**My Question:**

How can I write this HOC functional component to return a functional component instead of a class component? Or is there a better way?

**Functional Component That Returns A Class Component:**

```js
// Imports: Dependencies
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

// Component: Authorization
const AuthUserRole = (WrappedComponent, allowedRoles) => {
  class With AuthUserRole extends Component {
    render() {
      const userType  = this.props.userType;
      if (allowedRoles.includes(userType)) {
        return <WrappedComponent {...this.props} />;
      }
      else {
        return <h1>You are not allowed to view this page!</h1>;
      }
    }
  }

  const mapStateToProps = state => ({ user: state.login.userName, userType: state.login.userType });

  return connect(mapStateToProps)(AuthUserRole);
};

// Exports
export default AuthUserRole;
```

**App.js (Where HOC Is Used):**

```
<BrowserRouter history={history}>
  <Switch>
    {/* LANDING */}
    <Route path="/" component={Landing} exact />

    {/* APP */}
    <PrivateRoute path="/student/dashboard" component={Authorization(DashboardStudent,["Student"])}/>
    <PrivateRoute path="/admin/dashboard" component={Authorization(DashboardAdmin,["Admin"])}/>

    {/* LOGIN */}
    <Route path="/login" component={UserLogin}/>  

    {/* NOT FOUND */}
    <Route path="" component={NotFoundPage} />
  </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to return a function component, just return a function of `props`

```
const AuthUserRole = (WrappedComponent, allowedRoles) => {
   return (props) => {
...
   }
}
```

The [recommended best practice](https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide#use-the-react-redux-hooks-api) is to use the `useSelector` hook instead of `mapStateToProps` and `connect`.  So there are some other tweaks.

```
import React, { ComponentType } from 'react';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';

// Component: Authorization
const AuthUserRole = <Props extends {}>(WrappedComponent: ComponentType<Props>, allowedRoles: string[]) => {
  return (props: Props) => {
      // TODO: add your app's state type
      const userType = useSelector(state => state.login.userType);
      const user = useSelector(state => state.login.userName); // where is this used?

      if (allowedRoles.includes(userType)) {
        return <WrappedComponent {...props} />;
      }
      else {
        return <h1>You are not allowed to view this page!</h1>;
      }

  }
};

// Exports
export default AuthUserRole;
```

I added type annotations because you tagged this `typescript`, but I don't see any types in the current code.